# TreeView CSS Friendly Output? Control Adapters? ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008, xhtml, treeview

I want my TreeView control to output `<ul><li>` tags instead of `<tables>`.  What is the best way to do this.  I heard about the CSS Control Adapters.  Is this still the best way?  How do you go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you mean [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/TreeView.aspx)? Which is the still the best way that I know of. In the [HTML Snippets](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/TreeView.aspx) it doesn't render tables.

Your other option would be to build the control by hand just using plan old HTML and possibly a [Jquery Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/) to manipulate the tree.

Comment: No you have to download and install it. It was a MS project but it went open source about 3 years ago. It will work with VS 2008 as far as I am aware.