# How do I make .Net Framework 4 render asp:treeview as <ul> <li>?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, asp.net-4.0, html-lists

I have an `<asp:treeview>` control that looks like this:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvCategory" runat="server"  CssClass="CategoryTree" NodeStyle-CssClass="TreeNode TreeNodeUDF" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="TreeNodeSelected TreeNodeSelectedUDF">
</asp:TreeView>
```

This control renders in my page as a table. Is there any way to make .NET render it as `<ul><li>` tags, so I can easily assign a CSS class to it? I need to change the appearance of this TreeView so that it is oriented horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: in [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102232/asp-treeview-ul-li) Microsoft Write this in year 2005:
"we will look at providing the ability to template the TreeView rendering in a future release, so you could replace with a simple nested bulleted list rendering."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CSS control adaptors](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/TreeView.aspx), with [rendering mode not being available for the treeview control in .NET 4.0](http://forums.asp.net/t/1591664.aspx/1).  Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640158/treeview-css-friendly-output-control-adapters-asp-net-3-5) for a similar question.

Perhaps spare yourself the trouble and go for a [client side approach](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/)?